# How can I programmatically construct wrapper classes for POJOs with new annotations? Java

Tags: java, aop, bytecode, abstract-syntax-tree

Java has a lot of systems such as JPA, CDI, JAX-RS, and many many more where annotations decorate what is otherwise a POJO.

I end up authoring a lot of wrapper classes that do very little besides add some decorating annotations. I see a lot of code in the wild that re-wraps 3rd party POJOs with annotations- JAX-RS in particular often ends up with it's own suite of entities, even though they're backed by other simple POJOs or entities.

What kinds of options are available for reworking 3rd party POJOs? I'm not sure what I'm looking for exactly, but I imagine there'd be two major options: code generators powered by bytecode readers that produce wrappers, and options that modify the 3rd party POJO classes directly. what tools might help do either, and which way would you prefer to go, and why?